# Python Code input validation dictionary

Tags: python

I just created a python dictionary and it's executable. How can validate user input for instance to give an exception error if someone puts text instead of numbers in odometer reading? Below is the code. Thank you for feedback team.

```
Auto_details = {'Car brand': input('Car brand:'),
                'Car model': input('Car model:'),
                'Model Year': input('Model Year:'),
                'Starting odometer reading': int(input('Starting odometer reading:')),     
                'Ending odometer reading': int(input('Ending odometer reading:')),
                'Miles per gallon': int(input('Miles per gallon:')),
               }
print(Auto_details)
input ('Thank you. Please press Enter to exit')
```

Comment: Don't inline the `input`  calls into the `dict`, get user input field by field, check each entered value, only then build the `dict`.

Comment: Your code is _already_ doing exactly what you're asking for. `int(input('Starting odometer reading'))` will raise a `ValueError` exception if the user doesn't enter a number. So… what's the problem you actually need to solve here? Give us some sample input, and the desired vs. actual behavior.

Comment: Yes for the basic it's okay but I can put the word hello in odometer reading and this childish code takes it. I just want to learn how to restrict input. Thanks Lutz

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in this way:

```
def get_number(hint):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(hint))
        except ValueError:
            print('Please input a number')
            continue

        if value<0:
            print('Please input a positive value')
            continue
        else:
            break
    return value

Auto_details =     {'Car brand': input('Car brand:'),
                   'Car model': input('Car model:'),
                   'Model Year': input('Model Year:'),
                   'Starting odometer reading': get_number('Starting odometer reading:'),     
                   'Ending odometer reading': get_number('Ending odometer reading:'),
                   'Miles per gallon': get_number('Miles per gallon:'),
               }
print(Auto_details)
input ('Thank you. Please press Enter to exit')
```

Comment: Thanks my friend I will try it, I really want to master the syntax

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but it might work.

```
Auto_details = {}
phrases=[
    ["Car brand",False], ["Car model",False],
    ["Model year",False],["Starting odometer reading",True],
    ["Ending odometer reading",True],["Miles per gallon",True]
]

for phrase in phrases:
    answer=input(phrase[0])
    if phrase[1]:
        while True:
            if answer.isdigit():
                answer=int(answer)
                break
            answer=input(phrase[0])
    Auto_details[phrase[0]]=answer
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am learning the syntax. I appreciate it

Comment: Basically, I create an empty dictionary called `Auto_details` and a two-dimensional list `phrases` which has lists with `[phraseName,shouldBeInteger]`. I then loop through all of the phrases and ask for an input. If the input should be an integer, then I continuously ask for an input (using a `while True` loop) until it gives a correct one. Finally, I add the key and value of each phrase to the dictionary. I hope this helps and remember to hit the upvote button :-)